# Setup xterm-256color on Minix3

Tags: terminal, xterm, minix

## Problem

I'm trying to setup 256 color on Minix3. I found that the `xterm-256color` file exists on `/usr/pkg/share/terminfo/x`. I tried to set it up in `~/.profile` with

```
if [ -e /usr/pkg/share/terminfo/x/xterm-256color ]; then
        export TERM='xterm-256color'
else
        export TERM='xterm-color'
fi
```

However, when I do that I see garbage in the output of the terminal. Not sure what I am doing wrong. I search for information regarding the `ash` and `xterm`.

## Extra information

I searched `pkgin` and only found that `xtermset` is available, but `xterm` itself it isn't. Strangely several `xterm` are already installed in the previous path.

## Question

How can I setup Minix3 to have a 256 color terminal? Any hints or points on how to achieve that are welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Minix3 console supports only 8 colors.  If your terminfo database is reasonably recent, the recommended setting for `TERM` for the Minix3 console is [`minix`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-minix).

Setting `TERM` to other values will not change the number of colors available to you.  You can run other terminal emulators, if you are able to run X in your environment.  Some of those support 256 colors.

The `xterm` program can be built for Minux3 (I did that last year, for Minux 3.2, finding [some problems](http://invisible-island.net/autoconf/portability-test.html) with its antiquated shell which were fixed since then).  There is a port for xterm in pkgsrc (your question indicates that you are using pkgsrc).

Further reading:

- [Installing Binary Packages](http://wiki.minix3.org/doku.php?id=usersguide:installingbinarypackages) (MINIX 3)
- [Installing Source Packages](http://wiki.minix3.org/doku.php?id=usersguide:installingsourcepackages) (MINIX 3)

If someone has made a *binary package* for Minix3, it is available (prebuilt) with `pkgin`.  Otherwise, you can use `pkgsrc`, which provides far more packages.  Most (since Minix3 uses most of the "userland" from NetBSD) will build without problems.

Note however, that although the source-package page for Minix3 says

> [pkgsrc](http://www.netbsd.org/docs/software/packages.html) is used to build third-party software. This page describes how to use pkgsrc.

Minix is not listed on that site's [Supported platforms](http://www.netbsd.org/docs/software/packages.html#platforms).

Comment: I see from the documentation that `pkgsrc` is deprecated. Should I still try to use it? Or the replacement is the use of `git`? Also, what is the port you talk about? I can't find it with `pkgin`.